# How can I remove multi-line (Lua) comments in a bash script?

Tags: bash, sed, lua

I'm writing a bash script where I need to strip comments from Lua files, which are formatted:

```lua
--like this

foo="bar" --or like this

--[[ or like this ]]

--[[
    or
    like
    this
]]
```

I know I can use `sed 's/--.*$//' ${my_file}` to remove the single-line comments, but how can I address the multi-line one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all multi line matches start with `--[[` and end with `]]`, you can use a range match to address the multi-line as well as single line matches.

```
$ sed '/^--\[\[/,/\]\]/d' input_file
--like this

foo=bar --or like this
```

Implementing your original code can now clear the remaining comments that do not match the previous command.

```
$ sed '/^--\[\[/,/\]\]/d;s/--.*$//' input_file


foo=bar
```

To clean up, the empty lines can also be removed.

```
$ sed '/^--\[\[/,/\]\]/d;s/--.*//;/^$/d' input_file
foo=bar
```

Comment: yes, that's fine until the first person uses `--` in a string.

Comment: Thank you both! I was able to come up with this, which seems to work:

```lua
--like this

foo="bar" --or like this

bar="--not like this"

baz="--[[ not like this ]]"

--[[ or like this ]]

--[[
    or
    like
    this
]]
```

```shell
$ sed -e '/^--\[\[/,/\]\]/d' -e 's/^--.*//' -e 's/[^\"]--.*//' -e '/^$/d' test.lua
foo="bar"
bar="--not like this"
baz="--[[ not like this ]]"
```

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you can't format a code block in a comment. Anyway, the one liner is: `sed -e '/^--\[\[/,/\]\]/d' -e 's/^--.*//' -e 's/[^\"]--.*//' -e '/^$/d' test.lua`

Comment: I forgot about single-quotes. `sed -e '/^--\[\[/,/\]\]/d' -e 's/^--.*//' -e 's/[^\"'\'']--.*//' -e '/^$/d' test.lua`

Answer (score 2):

Nope, not really the job for a regular expression engine. For example, you can have `--` or `]]` perfectly legally in strings. And a string ends with `"`, but not with `\"`.

The idea of programming language doesn't map easily (in some cases, not at all, but this becomes an exercise in grammar theory) to regular expressions.

I'm not a language theorist myself, but I think lua might not define a regular grammar and hence might not be regex-parseable.

The way you'd implement this is by building a *lexer*, which reads the file, character for character, and divides them into *tokens* (like, this is a string token, which you start when you see a `"` and ends when you see an unescaped `"`). You emit all tokens that are *not* comments.

Comment: That makes sense, although I was hoping that wasn't the answer since parsing (obviously) isn't one of my strong skills. String literals containing `--` may be an edge case for me, so I think the other answer might be good enough. Thank you for your advice!